# Doctrine - Entity holds proxy after detaching for session management

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

### Context

I need to hold an entity into a session using Doctrine 2.3 (with PHP 5.4), and I'm having a problem once the `$_SESSION` variable is set.

### Code

I have the following classes:

#### Persistente

Superclass for holding information about persistent classes.

```
/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class Persistente
{
    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

#### Persona

Holds basic information about a person.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="id",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name="Persona_Id",
 *              type="integer"
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class Persona extends Persistente
{
    ...

    public function getContInformacion()
    {
        return $this->contInformacion;
    }

    public function setContInformacion(ContenedorInformacion $contInformacion)
    {
        $this->contInformacion = $contInformacion;
    }

    ...

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ContenedorInformacion", cascade={"all"}  )
     * @JoinColumn(name="ContInfo_Id", referencedColumnName="ContInfo_Id")
     */
    private $contInformacion;

}
```

#### ContenedorInformacion

Class that contains information about the person, which can be dynamically added to the object depending on some validation rules.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @AttributeOverrides({
 *      @AttributeOverride(name="id",
 *          column=@Column(
 *              name="ContInfo_Id",
 *              type="integer"
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class ContenedorInformacion extends Persistente
{
    ...

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UnidadInformacion", mappedBy="contInformacion", cascade={"all"}, indexBy="clave")
     */
    private $unidadesInformacion;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Rol", mappedBy="contInformacion", cascade={"all"}, indexBy="clave")
     */
    private $roles;

}
```

### Issue

Whenever I add `Persona` to a session, the following code gets executed:

```
public function login(Persona $t)
{
    if ($this->autorizar($t) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $dao = new DAOManejadorMsSql();
    $daoPersona = $dao->fabricarDAO("\Codesin\Colegios\Personas\Persona");
    $t = $this->buscarPersona($t);
    $daoPersona->soltar($t);
    $dao->cerrar();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $t;
    if ($t->getContInformacion()->existeRol('SYSADMIN') === true) {
        return 'SYSADMIN';
    }
}
```

`soltar()` executes the `detach()` method from the EntityManager, effectively leaving the entity unmanaged. However, the `ContenedorInformacion` object inside `Persona` is a proxy generated by Doctrine instead of the wanted object. Why does this happen? Thank you beforehand.

EDIT: This is the error.

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs/Zeus/lib/vendor/DoctrineProxies/__CG__/Codesin/Colegios/Personas/ContenedorInformacion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zeus\Common\Utils\autoload.php on line 8

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs/Zeus/lib/vendor/DoctrineProxies/__CG__/Codesin/Colegios/Personas/ContenedorInformacion.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Zeus\Common\Utils\autoload.php on line 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a very crude approach.

I figured out the following: given I'm not going to reattach the information immediately, I remade another `ContenedorInformacion` which contains the exact same information than the proxy. And given the `ArrayCollection`s aren't using proxies but rather the whole objects, I did this.

```
public function login(Persona $t)
{
    if ($this->autorizar($t) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    $dao = new DAOManejadorMsSql();
    $daoPersona = $dao->fabricarDAO("\Codesin\Colegios\Personas\Persona");
    $t = $this->buscarPersona($t);
    $daoPersona->soltar($t);
    $dao->cerrar();
    /***** NEW LINES START HERE *****/
    $contInfo = new ContenedorInformacion();
    $contInfo->setId($t->getContInformacion()->getId());
    $contInfo->setUnidadesInformacion(new ArrayCollection($t->getContInformacion()->getUnidadesInformacion()->toArray()));
    $contInfo->setRoles(new ArrayCollection($t->getContInformacion()->getRoles()->toArray()));
    $t->setContInformacion($contInfo);
    /***** NEW LINES END HERE *****/
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $t;
    if ($t->getContInformacion()->existeRol('SYSADMIN') === true) {
        return 'SYSADMIN';
    }
}
```

It's quite dirty, but it works like a charm.